# How to Edit Embedded Message on Discord When Role Has Been Assigned or Removed

Tags: discord.js

I am working on a Discord bot and I have an embed that shows the names of people who has that role, I want to make it edit that one message everytime the role is assigned or removed. Help would be very appreciated

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Client#guildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate). The event is fired whenever the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) is updated. (This includes: role added, role removed, nickname changes etc.)

Here's a simple example:

```js
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldGuildMember, newGuildMember) => {
    if (oldGuildMember.guild.id == "GuildID") { // Checking if the event was fired within the required Guild.
        if (!oldGuildMember.roles.cache.equals(newGuildMember.roles.cache)) { // Checking if the roles were changed.
            const Channel = client.channels.cache.get("ChannelIUD"); // Getting the channel your MessageEmbed is in.
            const Role = oldGuildMember.guild.roles.cache.get("RoleID"); // Getting the Role by ID.
            if (!Role || !Channel) return console.error("Invalid role or channel.");

            Channel.messages.fetch("MessageID").then(message => { // Getting the MessageEmbed as a Message by ID
                const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(); // Updating the MessageEmbed.
                Embed.addField(`Members of ${Role.name}`, Role.members.size > 0 ? `${Role.members.map(member => member.user.tag).join("; \n")};` : "This role has no members.");
                Embed.setColor("RED");
                message.edit(Embed).catch(error => console.error("Couldn't edit the message."));
            }).catch(error => console.error("Couldn't fetch the message."));
        };
    };
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a difference between `equals()` and `===` in this situation?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for asking. The `equals()` method of `Collection` is different to checking for equality using equal-signs, because the collections may be different objects, but contain the same data. Using the triple-equals sign will always return false.

Comment: I appreciate your answer man, but I put it in under events handler, I filled the other info to see if it works the way you showed it but it just doesn't do anything apparently :( I tried removing and assigning roles to myself and it just doesn't trigger :/

Comment: I placed it on my command and it works now, appreciate it kind sir :)